# What is the correct URL for MAGENTO admin

Tags: php, magento

I don't know why my magento is not working any more

when I hit "http://localhost.host/amuni/admin" it says

**Oops! This link appears to be broken.** but frontend working fine please tell me what should I do.

What is the correct URL?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try like this: http://localhost.host/amuni/index.php/admin

Note that "index.php" is added before "admin".

Comment: Just wanted to add the reason for accessing it through index.php is rewrites isn't enabled or supported by your server.

Answer (score 13):

**/index.php/admin is one solution, but there are others**

Although the above URL has worked for the original poster, it's not going to work for everybody. The Magento Admin Url is based on a custom value that is set during the installation. The url can also be changed at any time.

### Here's how to find out what your admin url is:

If the above solution does not work for you, then you'll need to access your local.xml file which is located in the /app/etc directory. Once you've opened that file, scroll to the bottom, around line 80 I think. You should see a tag called < frontEnd >. It's inside of this tag that your custom Magento Admin Url is located.

[image]

The source for this solution was found here, [finding your magento admin login](http://magentosupport.help/knowledgebase/what-is-the-magento-admin-url/).

Comment: In version 2.3 you can find the name in the /app/etc/env.php file at the frontName attribute